# Recovering a project in Visual C# Express 2010

Tags: visual-studio, projects-and-solutions, visual-c#-express-2010

I have been working on a service the last two days, saving the entire time with ctrl-s, testing, running, installing, etc.

I just went to the start page, and clicked on another project, without prompting me to save the whole project, it loaded the project I clicked on. I didn't even think about it.

I noticed I needed to look something up on the other project, and it is gone.

Comment: This will teach you to use  [source control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control).

Comment: Hasn't been the prompt for source control yet. That happens when I save the whole project. Problem was it didn't prompt me to save the whole project, and since I mainly work on web apps, I didn't think anything about it.

Comment: If you were hitting Ctrl-S then there should be some files on the hard drive somewhere. Check your (My) Documents area.

Comment: What do you mean by "it is gone"? Has the whole directory been deleted? Or can't you just find the project name on the start page? Have you looked in the "recent projects" menu?

Comment: No folder in the projects folder. Nothing I could find in temp either.

Comment: Also See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6381830/where-does-visual-c-sharp-2010-express-keep-its-temporary-files

Answer (score 0):

Did you use Save ALL (CTRL-SHIFT-S) or Save (CTRL-S)? IIRC, by default when you use CTRL-S VS2010Express saves your project in a temporary folder. When you use Save All, you will be prompted for a save location and that will save your project into the VS2010\Projects folder.

If you're 100% certain it's not in a temporary folder, then it's likely to be gone forever.

Edit: 1 year late, eh? lol