# Where does Visual C# 2010 Express keep it's temporary files?

Tags: visual-c#-express-2010

I worked on an application for a couple of days and saved files frequently with Ctrl+S. This morning I found out that my computer had force-restarted because of Windows security updates. Apparently Visual C# 2010 Express does not create a folder for project when the project is created. The project itself is saved only after "Save All" is issued.
Backup Files -folder contains a folder with project name but the folder is empty.

Is there any way to save at least part of the project?

Comment: when you press Ctrl+S it should save to your project.  Ctrl+S means 'Save', whereas Ctrl+Shift+S means 'Save All'.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11481137/visual-c-sharp-express-does-not-open-c-sharp-projects

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an old question, but I think the following answer will be helpful to other folks looking for this information.

VC Express saves temporary projects at C:\Documents and Settings*UserName*\Local Settings\Application Data\Temporary Projects.

You can turn off this behavior by checking: Tools > Options > Check "Show all settings" > Projects and Solutions > General > Check "Save new projects when created"