# Visual c# express does not open c# projects

Tags: visual-c#-express-2010

I was happy making an app in microsoft visual c# express, until i resarted my pc. After the restart, i try to open the same project and it does not open (does not say anything, just does not open anything) then, i opened the visual c# express, searched the project and it opens!!! But now everytime i work on a c# project, i have to open first the visual c# express and then look for the project. Other weird thing, is that the visual c# now run always as adminsitrator, so a windows is prompted every time i open it, does anybody know how to fix this?
TY

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm I would try just doing a fresh install of C# express and see if that fixes the issue. If not then it may possibly be an issue with your UAC level. Due to the fact that VS is running its own hosting process it may need more permissions than it is getting, if a re-install doesn't work try removing UAC authorization and running VS. If running without UAC doesn't work I would get in contact with Microsoft support.

For help removing UAC:
http://sshguy.hubpages.com/hub/DIsable-UAC---Complete-Disabling-Tutorial

Comment: A reinstall is quite overload... anything else?